# Let $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v} $ be two unit vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]
Let $ \vec{u} \ \ and \ \ \vec{v} \ $ be two unit vectors such that  $ < \vec{u} , \vec{v} >=\cos \theta $ . If $ \ \vec{v^{*}} $ be the mirror image of $ \vec{v} $ with respect to $ \vec{u} $  , then show that $ \ \vec{w}=(2 \cos \theta) [\vec{u}-\cos (\theta) \ \vec{v} ] \ \ $ .  **There is a hint:** First find  $ \vec{v^{*}} $ and then use **Gram-Schmidt** method. 
          $$ $$ From the formula the mirror image $ \vec{v^{*}} $ is given by $ \ \ \vec{v^{*}}=\vec{v}-2<\vec{u} ,\vec{v} >  \vec{u} =\vec{v}-(2 \cos \theta ) \vec{u} \ \  $ . But from this how to get $ \ \vec{w} \ $ using Gram-Schmidt method ? **Any help ?**

Comment: Actually what is $w$

Comment: From the figure i think  $ \vec{w} $ is perpendicular to  $ \vec{v} $

Comment: I guess it is $w= v - v^*$

Comment: then the answer is not coming. I think we have to use Gram -schimidth formula to find  $w $

Comment: yea, I know. But if $v^*$ is the mirror of $v$ w.r.t. $u$, then $v-v^*$ is perpendicular to $v$

Comment: So i think  $ w $  may not be perpendicular to $ v$ .

Comment: right, then it gets back to my original question: what is $w$?

Comment: it is not mentioned but given the figure only

Comment: yea, not quite clear. But from the answer, we kinda could back-engineer it as the projection of $u$ over $v$ minus the projection of $u$ over $v^*$

Answer (score 1):

Notice the question specifies $v^*$ to be the mirror vector of $v$ w.r.t $u$, but the $v^*$ you get is the projection vector of $v$ over $u$ - thus the $v^*$ you get is not the one specified by the question.

**Step 1**

Find $v^*$ as the mirror of $v$ w.r.t. $u$, i.e.
$$v^*=2\langle u,v\rangle u-v$$

**Step 2**

Use Gram-Schmidt to find projection of $u$ over $v$, and let's call it $x$; and find projection of $u$ over $v^*$, and let's call it $x^*$

**Step 3**
$$w=x - x^*$$